# How do I record the VirtualBox screen to a file?

Tags: virtualbox, display, recording

I'm using non-OSE VirtualBox which seems to support recording the VM screen to a file.

```
VBoxHeadless -c -f record.avi -s myvm
```

But somehow it complains with the following message:

> Failed to load the video capture extension

Any idea how to enforce it?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: It is ubuntu linux.

Comment: Have you installed VirtulBox Guest Additions?

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal: sure

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the VirtualBox distribution itself, which now lacks the required modules.

If you took a look in the module [VBoxHeadless.cpp](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Frontends/VBoxHeadless/VBoxHeadless.cpp), you would see that for this to function, the following conditions must be fulfilled :

1. VBOX_FFMPEG must be defined
2. The VBoxFFmpegFB shared library must be available with entry-point VBoxRegisterFFmpegFB

In the thread [VBoxHeadless "Failed to load the video capture extension"](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=18895) from 2009, someone named xantus has tried to create the required conditions by modifying the sources accordingly, but this didn't work.

I suggest that the proper way to go about it, is to address the developers on the [VirtualBox forums](http://forums.virtualbox.org/) and convince them to get it working again, although this option seems to have been abandoned since at least 2009.